# Help with workflow that always fires

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow that always fires and can't figure out why. Here is the logic:

1. We use an incoming email handler to edit records based on a keyword in the email body
2. I want the workflow to fire only when an unrecognized keyword is received (valid keywords are Yes, No, or Stop and these are received correctly. We store them in a lastcommand__c field converted to lowercase to verify.

Here is the rule:
[image: Image of Bad Rule Criteria]

Here is the part of the DEBUG log I captured (and action correctly executes, telling the recipient the command they sent was invalid per the configured email action/template). In this case the response was "yes."

```
21:09:46.0 (101905360)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Enrollment: Enrollment27940 a0dq0000001Z5uo]|WHW Unknown RSVP Response Workflow|01Qq00000005bvN|ON_ALL_CHANGES|0
21:09:46.0 (102066068)|WF_RULE_FILTER|[Enrollment : First RSVP Sent equals true] AND
 [Enrollment : RSVP Request Sent Date not equal to ] AND
 ([Enrollment : Last Message Received not equal to yes] OR
 [Enrollment : Last Message Received not equal to no] OR
 [Enrollment : Last Message Received not equal to stop])
21:09:46.0 (102088626)|WF_RULE_EVAL_VALUE|1
21:09:46.0 (102104725)|WF_RULE_EVAL_VALUE|2017-04-18 04:09:11
21:09:46.0 (102111404)|WF_RULE_EVAL_VALUE|yes
21:09:46.0 (102113967)|WF_RULE_EVAL_VALUE|yes
21:09:46.0 (102116639)|WF_CRITERIA_END|true
```

This DEBUG log shows "" (null) as being the message received, but will also eval to be true if "yes" or "no" or anything else is received. Is this just bad logic, should conditions be changed to a formula, anything else?

Comment: Can you explain the `RSVP Request Sent Date` and `First RSVP Sent` used in the workflow.? Also `RSVP Request Sent Date` will have `null` value if it's not filled. So use `RSVP Request Sent Date not equal to null` in your workflow. That makes more sense.

Comment: one question, every time your record fulfill the WF criteria , it will fire or it will fire only once??

Comment: Yes, just once. But if you change the answer it'll fire again.

Comment: Both RSVP Sent Date and First RSVP Sent are custom fields. 

RSVP Sent Date is a date/time that I populate via trigger to ensure we record the date/time the very first message is initiated and is set to null by default. My thinking here is that if the RSVP wasn't sent out to begin with it'll still be null and therefore make the rule not fire (hope this makes sense)

First RSVP Sent is a true/false that it was sent and is also updated via trigger, as well.

Comment: As per my understanding you workflow need to fire lastcommand__c doesn't contain yes or no or stop.If it is your requirement why you are not mentioning this in your criteria.@Mike Stan

Comment: My apologies, Last_Message_received__c is where we store the last command that is received in the message body (too late to update comment). It fires on anything: 1) null (on a new record when there is nothing in there); 2) yes; 3) no; 4) stop; 5) anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter Logic should be `and` not `or`. No single value can be all of those so `or` *not equals* will always eval to true

Comment: So, 

`1 AND 2 AND 3 and 4 and 5` ?

Comment: Yup. As long as blank should not fire it as well.  Otherwise remove the blank check

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. This is _mostly_ working in that when I receive the initial message to prompt me to reply with my yes/no/stop keyword, the `Last_Message_Received` in indeed null (it's a new record).

I'm going to try 2 things to fix this up perfect: 1) add a condition that looks for `Last_Message_Received is not null`;  **or** 2) set the initial value for this field to something like "new" so it will never start out as null (and if someone responds with a null keyword, will fire the email triggers I need).